# InternetConnect returns error 12002 when attempting to connect to a sftp server

Tags: c++, winapi

Given the following code that should connect to a `sftp` server and print the name of the first file in that server. It looks like it returns the error [12002](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/193625/info-wininet-error-codes-12001-through-12156) which means that the request timed out. I've tried to run it with 2 different servers. Is there something fundamentally wrong in my code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

int main()
{

    HINTERNET hInternet =  InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

    if (hInternet == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("An error has occured while trying to open the internet connection\n"));
        return 1;
    }

    HINTERNET hFTP = InternetConnect(
        hInternet,
        L"test.rebex.net", // this is a sftp server publicly available
        22,
        L"demo",
        L"password",
        INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,
        INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,
        0
    );

    if (hFTP == NULL)
    {
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        _tprintf(_T("Couldn't connect to the ftp server\n"));
        return 1;
    }

    _tprintf(_T("%d\n"), hFTP);

    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;

    FtpFindFirstFile(hFTP, L".", &fd, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, NULL);

    _tprintf(_T("%s"), fd.cFileName);

    InternetCloseHandle(hFTP);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFTP (FTP over SSH) is very different than FTPS (FTP over SSL), which is probably what you want instead.

But either way, WinInet simply does not support SFTP or FTPS (the `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` flag is only supported for HTTPS).

You will have to use another FTP library that supports SFTP/FTPS.