# MFC. Inquire about GetFtpConnection Method in CInternetSession class

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a question about `GetFtpConnection` method in `CInternetSession` class.

It is possible to connect 21 port.
But it's impossible to connect 22 port as `sftp`. When I connect the 22 port, timeout error is happened.

So I am wondering that `GetFtpConnection` method has a `sftp` connection function.

If this method is possible to connect port 22 as `sftp`, I want to know the reason why timeout error happened and how to fix it.

but, impossible to connect port 22, Is there another way to sftp library?

Please answer me. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think MFC supports sftp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InternetConnect returns error 12002 when attempting to connect to a sftp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540276/internetconnect-returns-error-12002-when-attempting-to-connect-to-a-sftp-server)